# Big O complexity with n^2 log(n)

Tags: big-o, logarithm

Two questions:

First, if f(n) = n(3n + nlog(n)) then why is f(n) Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Second, why is n<sup>2</sup>log(n) not O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. I had wrongly concluded the first part of your question. Have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

These are both consequences of the fact that log(n) tends to infinity as n tends to infinity.

1) n(3n + nlog(n)) is omega(n^2) because for large n the 3n is negligible and n^2log(n) is bounded below by n^2

2) n^2log(n) is *not* O(n^2) since, for any constant K > 0, for any n > e^K you have that n^2log(n) > Kn^2, so no K satisfies n^2log(n) < Kn^2 for all but finitely many n.

Answer (score 0):

Ω( ) is for putting the bound under the function. That means that the function will have running time complexity at least more that what is mentioned between the parentheses in Ω( ). Now, for the function `f(n) = n(3n + nlog(n))`, the dominating function out of the two functions involved (*3n<sup>2</sup>* and *n<sup>2</sup>Log(n)*) is *n<sup>2</sup>Log(n)*.

Therefore, any function smaller than the dominating function can act as the lower bound even if it may not be the tightest possible lower bound. So, **f(n) is Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

---

Next, growth rate of n<sup>2</sup>Log(n) is higher than n<sup>2</sup> (as I already mentioned above which one is dominating). Therefore, n<sup>2</sup>Log(n) is a tighter bound (and therefore a better determinant) about the Big - O of f(n). Hence, **f(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>Log(n)) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>).**